# Generating Unique Invoice tracking in dot net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cryptography, tracking, salt, saltedhash

I need to produce a unique tracking number with only 10 digits in length.

as i google the only usefull article from stackoverflow [Generating unique tracking numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656556/generating-unique-tracking-numbers)

but this is not dot net code. i try to find find a way to write dot net equivelant of this code but i can not do it.

```
>>> int(hashlib.sha256(str(1) + "!salt!").hexdigest()[:13], 16)
1269883740611281
>>> int(hashlib.sha256(str(2) + "!salt!").hexdigest()[:13], 16)
3655373802716929
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: With only 10 digits. Great. Here you go: 1.000.000.000 - 9.999.999.999. Enjoy.

Comment: In asp.net there are Guids https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Comment: what you mean by GUIDs.GUIDs are not good for invoice tracking number.

Comment: Then why don't you store the current invoice tracking number and then start from 1.000.000.000 and go up to 9.999.999.999 by adding 1. It's silly, these are all 10 digits numbers.

Comment: And if you don't want only 10 digits you will need to store it like a non-int non-guid unique identifier which is a TERRIBLE idea.

Comment: "GUIDs are not good for invoice tracking number."                                **Assuming uniform probability for simplicity, the probability of one duplicate would be about 50% if every person on earth as of 2014 owned 600 million GUIDs.** OK.

Comment: Tracking numbers must not predictable by users.

Comment: 3655373802716929 and 1269883740611281 aren't predictible.

Comment: If you generate like a 10 digits number the user will have 8.999.999.999 possibilities to try. The guid generates 5.3×10^36 possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the code that you are using there uses a hash. Hash values are not unique. The hash seems to be misused here as a random number generator. Instead, use an RNG directly:

```
new Random().Next(1000 * 1000 *1000, 1000 * 1000 *1000 * 10).ToString()
```

You can use web search to find a cryptographically strong way to generate random numbers in that range.

You can have more possible tracking codes by using letters as well.